# 'Error calling CreateEnvelope' when attempting to create a DocuSign envelop with the C# SDK

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I'm trying to create an envelope for signing using the C# DocuSign SDK. I have a developer account set up, and a local, signable pdf. Attempting to call `CreateEnvelopeAsync` results in a non-descriptive `Error calling CreateEnvelope: ''` error. Here is my setup:

```
DocuSignClient apiClient = new(options.OAuthBasePath); // set to "demo.docusign.net"
EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new(apiClient);

var accessToken = GetAccessToken(apiClient, options);

var request = new SignatureRequest()
{
    DocumentFilepath = "path/to/file.pdf",
    EmailSubject = "Subject",
    EnvelopeStatus = "sent",
    Signers = new()
    {
        new DocumentSigner()
        {
            Email = "valid@email.com",
            Name = "First Last"
        }
    }
};

var result = await RequestSignature(request);
```

Generating tokens works fine

```
public static string GetAccessToken(DocuSignClient apiClient, DocuSignOptions options)
{
    List<string> scopes = new() { "signature", "impersonation" };

    var pkey = File.ReadAllText(options.PrivateKeyPath);
    var pkeyBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pkey);

    using var pkeyStream = new MemoryStream(pkeyBytes);
    pkeyStream.Position = 0;

    var token = apiClient.RequestJwtUserToken(
        options.IntegrationKey,
        options.UserId,
        "account-d.docusign.com",
        pkeyStream,
        options.JwtExpiration,
        scopes);

    return token.access_token;
}
```

Moving on to the actual request

```
public async Task<EnvelopeSummary> RequestSignature(SignatureRequest request)
{
    string documentData = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(request.DocumentFilepath));
    string documentName = Path.GetFileName(request.DocumentFilepath);
    string documentExtension = Path.GetExtension(request.DocumentFilepath);

    EnvelopeDefinition envelope = new()
    {
        EmailSubject = request.EmailSubject,
        Status = request.EnvelopeStatus,
        Documents = new()
        {
            new()
            {
                DocumentBase64 = documentData,
                Name = documentName,
                FileExtension = documentExtension,
                DocumentId = "1",
            },
        },
        Recipients = new()
        {
            Signers = request.Signers
                .Select((signer, idx) => new Signer()
                {
                    Email = signer.Email,
                    Name = signer.Name,
                    RecipientId = idx.ToString(),
                    RoutingOrder = idx.ToString(),
                })
                .ToList(),
        }
    };

    var result = await envelopesApi.CreateEnvelopeAsync(accountId, envelope);

    return result;
}
```

Stepping through the decompiled code with the debugger, the internal HTTP call seems to return null, but I'm not sure how reliable that is.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: You are sending a request and getting a response.  Since you are getting a token the connection is probably good when you perform the query.  Do you get a response with no data or you never get a response?  If you are not getting a response the server is hung up.  Check server for errors.  The query could be taking a long time.  If you are getting a response than it means the query did not return any data.

Comment: I don't think the http call is taking too long. The actual response I seem to be getting is `null`, but again, that's with debugging external code, which from experience hasn't always been reliable since optimizations sometimes mess with the flow of things. Since the response is `null`, there's no associated error message either, which makes things harder to debug. I guess a next step would be to test a few different endpoints to narrow things down.

Comment: Check event viewer on server.  No response indicates the connection terminated.  You are getting the token which means the server is running and responding.  The server is just rejecting the query.  With email you need to have a FROM address and the FROM has to be from the same account as the credentials.  I think the server thinks your code is a hacker and not responding.  So most likely it is either the credentials or the FROM.  The connection is breaking and you are just reaching a timeout.

Comment: Can you try to use our C# quickstart and see if it works for you? You're using some more advanced C# features and that code is more basic and if that code doesn't work - we will know the issue is related to connection and not the C# SDK not supporting latest and greatest C#/.NET features

Comment: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/